# I am trying to share a file over WebRTC but after some time it stops, and log RTCDatachannel send queue is full

Tags: webrtc, p2p, peerjs, real-time-data, simple-peer

```
let file = fileUpload.files[0];
let offset = 0;
let chunkSize = 1024*1024*16;


file.arrayBuffer().then((buffer) => {
            
 while(buffer.byteLength){
                
       const chunk = buffer.slice(0, chunkSize);
       buffer = buffer.slice(chunkSize, buffer.byteLength);
      dataChannel.send(chunk);
  }
})
```

it works fine for small files but stops with big size files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DataChannel` has a `bufferedAmount` property which tells you how many bytes are still waiting to be sent. It also has a property called `bufferedAmountLowThreshold`.

> The RTCDataChannel property bufferedAmountLowThreshold is used to specify the number of bytes of buffered outgoing data that is considered "low."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/bufferedAmountLowThreshold
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/bufferedAmount

You could keep sending data as normal as long as `bufferedAmount` is below `bufferedAmountLowThreshold`. Once it is larger you stop queuing more data until you receive a `bufferedamountlow` event.

```
const send = () => {
  while (buffer.byteLength) {
    if (dataChannel.bufferedAmount > dataChannel.bufferedAmountLowThreshold) {
      dataChannel.onbufferedamountlow = () => {
        dataChannel.onbufferedamountlow = null;
        send();
      };
      return;
    }
    const chunk = buffer.slice(0, chunkSize);
    buffer = buffer.slice(chunkSize, buffer.byteLength);
    dataChannel.send(chunk);
  }
};
send();
```